# Bug with automatic reminder message for ID-tags

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, identify

There currently seems to be a bug with the [automatic message](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1419/49) popping up whenever a question is asked/edited with an ID-tag ([identify-this-movie](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identify-this-movie), [identify-this-tv-show](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identify-this-tv-show), ...). The reminder message, that should just kindly remind you to include any possible meta-information seems to suddenly be treated as a hard error, making it impossible to ask or edit the question as long as it has this tag.

Seeing that this feature worked well for a long time and this bug is only ocurring rather recently (first encountered with [this question](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/27793/49)), there seems to be something off. This should be investigated as fast as possible, since it basically prevents people from asking any kind of ID question (as much as I personally like this situation ;-)), or even worse, makes them ask those questions without proper tagging or possibility for retagging. If this is not solvable that easily/fast, the automatic message should simply be disabled for now (unfortunately this seems to be a feature not even accessible to moderators but only to SE staff).

Comment: Related report on [meta.se]: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/244607/162011

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer from linked question:

> You should be able to submit posts with validation warnings again
>   after build rev 2014.12.3.2063 rolls out.

This build has now rolled out. This should be fixed.