# Feature - Guidelines for Identify-This Questions - Reposition?

Tags: feature-request, design, identify

Someone uses the `identify-this-movie` tag and a new section pops up between the Tags section and the `Post` button that gives some help and some clarifications of common stuff people forget to add to their questions.

1. It doesn't actually appear when you click the Tag autofill, only when you click off the Tag Text area.
2. It appeared so far off to the right that I didn't actually see it until I looked for it.

Image of what I see (this image is scaled down to some extent):
[image: Image of Pop-up]

I get that this is a supermod issue but I feel like this box would be more useful and eye-catching if it could appear more like this and appear without having to click out of the text area:

[image: Placement suggestion]

Despite this box existing, clearly it's not effective and I wonder if the placement is part of that, particularly if the box doesn't even appear until you click out of the box... and the average person's next click would be on the Post button.

Comment: Previously proposed: [Country Of Origin should be a required field](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1194/country-of-origin-should-be-a-required-field)

Comment: @JohnnyBones That is a very specific request for one piece of information. I feel that this is a very different request, particularly as it's not required, it's just some "before you submit, make your question as good as you can" notes.

Comment: We bantered about some ides in the discussion section that I thought covered this to some degree, which is why I didn't downvote or vote to close but merely posted the link (so you (or others) can see what was discussed).  Country of Origin was a big one for me, but Year and Genre are extremely important as well in helping identify a movie.

Comment: Related: [Automatically remind users for the age, country and language of a film](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1419/49) (if not even duplicate).

Comment: @NapoleonWilson yes... that would be a great option. Is there any sort of update? I would agree that we're asking the same thing.

Comment: Nevermind... I reread and it seems like the answer is - No, you can't has. Which is kinda lame.

Comment: @Catija Well, I just tried it and it works. Ask a question and give it the `identify-this-movie` tag and that box should pop up. If it doesn't work for you, that would be a bug. Though, I think it's not yet implemented for `-tv-show`. But unfortunately it's hard to tweak, as I think not even mods can chnage this behaviour but only SE übermods.

Comment: @Catija Oh wait, I just realized it doesn't show up until you actually type some question text (which might make sense). Wait, I think the tag box has to lose focus, which might not be best, since tags are often the last things you add. Well, the feature's certainly far from being perfect yet, but it's there and *"yes, you can has"*.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson So... it does show up. HA HA... but it's so far over on the right side, I didn't see it.  It's like it needs to hover where the tag is rather than at the end, that's why I thought it would help if it was obscuring or moving the submit button.  Oh well.

Comment: @Catija Too far on the right side? The thing's right under the formatting help and glowing in bright green. You're not working on a good old 640x480 display, are you? ;-)

Comment: @NapoleonWilson Yours is green? Mine is Ochre Yellow... I added an image.  If you're just asking a question, and aiming for the big red submit button, you're not going to see the box over on the right. And I'm on a perfectly high-res 15-inch laptop screen. :P

Comment: @Catija Given that it pops up out of nothing, that effect should help to draw attention. I'm not sure how far we should really go here. If your question is about technicalities of the given feature instead of a proposal for a new feature ignoring the exitsing one, you might want to update the question to reflect that, because at the moment it seems the question answers itself with the accompanied image.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson I don't mind updating the question but if this feature is something that's above the heads of anyone other than ubermods, I don't know if it serves a purpose to do that.

Comment: @Catija Why not? Your dissatisfied with a feature and propose a change on meta, how else should that change be accomplished at all, no matter *who* does it at the end. The original feature didn't get implemented out of the blue either, but after a standard meta question. If you keep silent then sure, nobody will change it.

Comment: I am agree with 1st point but 2nd point is not much required in that sense And it should be added to -tv-shows too